# WearableListItemLayout: Remove item height limit

Tags: android, android-listview, wear-os

In Android Wear I'm using an `WearableListView` with `WearableListView.Adapter` to show items in a list. I have a custom layout for each item that has the parent `WearableListItemLayout` but it's problematic because the items are limited to approximately/exactly `80dp`. I understand this is because of the "snapping" effect and follows the guidelines throughout the Android Wear system. My plan here is not to go outside of these guidelines more than a few dp's and I cannot make more sacrifices to the parts of the item (I have already chosen a too small font, too small icons etc..).

#### Item

```
<com.strafe.android.view.WearableListItemLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:minHeight="100dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="100dp"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dp">

    <!-- Textviews and other stuff -->

    </RelativeLayout>

</com.strafe.android.view.WearableListItemLayout>
```

The code above cuts the item's TextViews and other parts of the item making it only `80dp` high **no matter if i have `minHeight="100dp"`**.

Is there any way to remove this limitation?

Answer (score 0):

I think the device you are using has a screen of 240dp; the WearableListView is designed to work on Wearable devices in a way that each item takes exactly 1/3 of the screen height so in a 240dp display, each item will be 80dp and you cannot change that.

Comment: So, there is no way around this?

Comment: as long as you use WearableListView, you have that limitation, no work around that.